# Apply a function to each row and the subsequent row by group

Tags: r, r-sf

I have an sf dataframe containing points that mark the locations of intersections along many *one-way* streets. In addition to the geometry column, one column contains the street name, and another contains the intersection's relative position on the one-way street.

Below is a toy example. The first row is the first intersection on Arch St., the second row is the 2nd intersection on Arch St, etc.

```
library(sf)

intersections <- structure(list(street = c("ARCH ST", "ARCH ST", "ARCH ST", "SANSOM ST", 
"SANSOM ST", "SANSOM ST"), number = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), 
    geometry = structure(list(structure(c(2699665.2606043, 236074.947200272
    ), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(2699402.74765515, 
    236109.729280198), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(2699202.95996668, 
    236136.613760229), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(2699431.38476158, 
    234437.663731016), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(2699162.09261096, 
    234476.514355583), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(2697100.77148795, 
    234809.605567052), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 2697100.77148795, 
    ymin = 234437.663731016, xmax = 2699665.2606043, ymax = 236136.613760229
    ), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(epsg = 2272L, proj4string = "+proj=lcc +lat_1=40.96666666666667 +lat_2=39.93333333333333 +lat_0=39.33333333333334 +lon_0=-77.75 +x_0=600000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-ft +no_defs"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L, class = c("sfc_POINT", 
    "sfc"))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("sf", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(street = NA_integer_, 
number = NA_integer_), class = "factor", .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity")))

> intersections
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 2697101 ymin: 234437.7 xmax: 2699665 ymax: 236136.6
epsg (SRID):    2272
proj4string:    +proj=lcc +lat_1=40.96666666666667 +lat_2=39.93333333333333 +lat_0=39.33333333333334 +lon_0=-77.75 +x_0=600000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-ft +no_defs

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  street    number                 geometry
  <chr>      <int> <POINT [US_survey_foot]>
1 ARCH ST        1       (2699665 236074.9)
2 ARCH ST        2       (2699403 236109.7)
3 ARCH ST        3       (2699203 236136.6)
4 SANSOM ST      1       (2699431 234437.7)
5 SANSOM ST      2       (2699162 234476.5)
6 SANSOM ST      3       (2697101 234809.6)
```

Using `mp_matrix()` and `mp_get_matrix()` from the `mapsapi` package, I would like to add a column that shows the travel time from each intersection to the next intersection on that street (except for the last intersection, which gets an NA).

Ideally, it would look like the below:

```
     street number travel_time_sec                 geometry
1   ARCH ST      1             210 POINT (2699665 236074.9)
2   ARCH ST      2             180 POINT (2699403 236109.7)
3   ARCH ST      3              NA POINT (2699203 236136.6)
4 SANSOM ST      1             150 POINT (2699431 234437.7)
5 SANSOM ST      2             175 POINT (2699162 234476.5)
6 SANSOM ST      3              NA POINT (2697101 234809.6)
```

**How can I loop over rows in an sf dataframe by group (i.e. the street), tell each row to perform operations with the next row in that group to populate a new column, and return an NA if no such next row exists?**

Lastly, since `mp_matrix()` calls the Google Maps API, which costs money, please instead use the `st_distance()` function from `sf` to generate the below.

```
     street number travel_distance                 geometry
1   ARCH ST      1             576 POINT (2699665 236074.9)
2   ARCH ST      2             397 POINT (2699403 236109.7)
3   ARCH ST      3              NA POINT (2699203 236136.6)
4 SANSOM ST      1             410 POINT (2699431 234437.7)
5 SANSOM ST      2             440 POINT (2699162 234476.5)
6 SANSOM ST      3              NA POINT (2697101 234809.6)
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was playing around with your example and I was not able to get the same `travel distance` with the `st_distance` function.

```
st_distance(intersections$geometry[1], intersections$geometry[2])

Units: [US_survey_foot]
         [,1]
[1,] 264.8072
```

The loop or vectorized operation through the rows itself could be done with this piece of code

```
# used librarys
library(units)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

# find distance function
find_Distance <- function(x) {

  # create lead list
  x_lead <- x[2:length(x)]

  # create distance matrix
  distance_matrix <- st_distance(x, x_lead)

  # diagonal of the distance matrix is your desired output, fill last entry with NA and 
  # unit
  c(diag(distance_matrix), set_units(NA, "US_survey_foot"))

}

# group by street and calculate distance
intersections <- group_by(intersections, street) %>%
  mutate(travel_distance = find_Distance(geometry))

# if needed, set unit of travel distance
units(intersections$travel_distance) <- as_units("US_survey_foot")
```

Comment: Thank you.  I should have clarified that my `travel_distance` values were just dummies. One challenge is generating a dense matrix and taking the diagonal with my actual use case, `mp_matrix()`, would be highly costly. Unlike `st_distance()`, `mp_matrix()` does not have a `by_element` (pairwise) argument, so a dense matrix output is the only option. I solved the problem by adding your `lead` column, transforming `intersections` into a list where every element is a df row, and `lapply()`ing `mp_matrix()`. The resultant matrices were 1x1, and I joined those values back to the original df.